# What is the difference between Publications and Subscriptions in meteor

Tags: meteor

Today I started to learn meteor. I just came across some publications and subscriptions. Is there any example to understand the difference between publications and subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/pubsub

A publication is what the server offers in term of data. A subscription is what the client uses to read inside a publication.

You can see it as magazines or something similar... Some guys publish X mag, Y mag and Z mag. Those 3 mags are available in store, but you really like reading about Y, so you subscribe to it to make sure you have all the fresh content, very fast.

EDIT:
Publications should take a big part of your time spent on securing your app data... Those rules will determine what the users get from your server, some of which should certainly remain on the server!!

Comment: As you are new to meteor, I would like to point out the autopublish package... It comes in every new meteor app and automatically publishes the whole database. This means the pubsub patterns are useless until the package is removed.

Answer (score 2):

Another good Pub / Sub explanation is from the [http://www.discovermeteor.com blog](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/)